# Pdf files as part of Android .apk

Tags: android, security, pdf, installation

I have to build an Android application which shows a list of pdf files. These pdf files should be secured, in other words - the user of the app should not be able to get a copy of the pdf content by any means (copy/cut/print...etc). My questions now are

1. How should I ship the content of the pdf file along with .apk file.
2. If we send the content of the file in a diff format (raw/byte code), how should I convert the file back to pdf and where should I place the file on the installed machine such that it is secure.

FYI, I will be locking down current version of Adobe Redaer as the pdf viewer to view the pdf files as it doesn't allow copy/paste/print.

This is the first Android app that I am developing. So, I'm a kind of Android newbie. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Navin

Comment: You need to come to terms with the fact that it will be pretty trivial to extract the PDFs, and build your business plan around that reality.

Comment: @Chris : Hi Chris, I did not get you completely? Did you meant to say that its easy to extract pdf files irrespective of where they are stored on the machine? Help me understand please. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, they will be easy to extract.  And doubly so if you hand them off to another application for display.  You cannot base your strategy on trusting the handset.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy this(these) pdf file(s) into assets folder, thus your files will be the part of your application and can not be accessible outside, and you can also treat them as normal files (i.e. open with any pdf viewer in your case). Whenever you want to get access to context file you can call `context.getAssets()` .

Hope this information helps.

**Update :** Here is the code I am using to open a file in downloads directory, this code can open the pdf file in any compatible pdf reader if installed on phone, Tested with Adobe Reader. You will need a URI of the pdf file in assets folder to run the code.

```
String fileName = pdfUrl.substring(pdfUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));

        Log.i("fileName", "" + fileName);
        File file = new File("/sdcard/download" + fileName);
        // File file = new
        // File("/sdcard/download/airtel_latest000.mp3");

        Intent intent;
        if (file.exists()) {

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            downloaded = true;

        } else {

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setData(Uri.parse(pdfUrl));

            downloaded = false;
        }
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 5);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Application Available to View PDF",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I was able to ship the pdf files by putting them in this folder. but when I read it using the AssetManager(which I believe is the only way we can read the files in these folder), I only get a byteStream.  Does this mean we cant read the pdf files as they are when we place in this folder. Or am i missing something here?  Is there any other way we can deal this?                                                     Thanks,

Comment: The storing in asset folder is the solution to hide your files and bundle with your apk. To open the file in pdf reader you must have a url or uri for that. I am editing my answer to add the code I use, do give a look to it and use it if you find it useful.

Comment: You are seriously mistaken if you think that putting the files in a given folder will protect them.  They are readable on a rooted device, or by copying off the .apk to a pc, renaming to .zip and decompressing it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should store it in the [res/raw folder](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/display-text-file-in-resraw_01.html)

Comment: I am not able to copy pdf files here as it is throwing the following error:                                                                                 [2011-02-24 18:22:13 - CSGRealizeTab] res\raw\CSGSample.pdf: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]                                  And if I place it in the assets folder, i can read the files placed there only in byte format. Do you know of any other way to implement this?  Thank you very much

Comment: You have uppercase letters in the file name, it needs to be all lower case.